# How to detect a REQ connect event to ROUTER

Tags: node.js, zeromq

**What I want?**

Whenever the **`REQ`** connects with `requester.connect()` call to that `host:port`, **`ROUTER`** should detect this event and `do something` i.e. in this case `cluster.fork();`

I tried:

```
       //Start Evented Child Node Processes alongwith a Request REQ Each
        router.on("accept", function funcCB (fileDesc, endPt) {
            //fire up a cluster fork for handling Requests
            console.log("starting a new FORK process");
            cluster.fork();
        });
```

What `router.on(<event>)` should actually detect a

```
requester.connect()
```

??

As per this [**here**](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node) these are the monitor events available for node zmq:

These are the triggered events as per the doc there:

```
connect - ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED
connect_delay - ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_DELAYED
connect_retry - ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_RETRIED
listen - ZMQ_EVENT_LISTENING
bind_error - ZMQ_EVENT_BIND_FAILED
accept - ZMQ_EVENT_ACCEPTED
accept_error - ZMQ_EVENT_ACCEPT_FAILED
close - ZMQ_EVENT_CLOSED
close_error - ZMQ_EVENT_CLOSE_FAILED
disconnect - ZMQ_EVENT_DISCONNECTED
```

Comment: What was not functional with your attempt to trigger on the "accept" event, which should be the correct one?  Did you actually start the `router.monitor()`, per [this example](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node#example)?

Comment: @Jason let me test this. i think that would be the issue. ill get back to u in a while

Comment: @Jason works like charm. thanks!

Comment: glad it was that easy :)

Comment: @Jason yeah thanks ! works like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

### How it works?

The beauty of **`ZeroMQ`** is in it's architecture. This means, the abstract scaleable archetype primitives ( `PUB` / `SUB`, `PAIR`, `XREQ` ) do exactly what these have been defined for.

The clean architecture separates **`I/O-thread`**(s) from socket's-entry-gate "**behaviour**" and keeps all the dirty stuff down there::
[image]

This said, it is of no use say I want **`ROUTER`** to detect and handle also this and that, if it was not defined to do this right in the **`ZeroMQ`** architecture.

### How to do it?

The simplest approach to this and similar need is to design one's own **composite element**, let's for the simplicity sketch it as [`[ROUTER]`+`[SUB]`], where the node has both the **`[ROUTER]`**-trafic-oriented behaviour and also keeps a **`[SUB]`**-signalling-receiving behaviour, exposed to outer world via `SUB.bind()` at another `host:portSIG`

This way, remote processes `REQ.connect( host:port)` and `PUB.connect( host:portSIG )` and operate on both the transport-plane and the signalling-plane as your design needs and implements.

**`ZeroMQ`** is a lovely can-do LEGO-toolbox.
[image]
Enjoy these powers.

Comment: Is this a wiki?
The Q I am asking is IS there a way to detect via ZMQ ROUTER to detect a successful connection event?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was this small addition as posted by @Jason [here on the SO comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085891/how-to-detect-a-req-connect-event-to-router?noredirect=1#comment54024518_33085891)

```
//start the socket ROUTER monitor
            router.monitor(500, 0);
```